# NativeScript - how can I filter an observable array with SearchBar?

Tags: filtering, observablecollection, nativescript

Hi I'm trying to filter an observable array of data fetched via a HTTP request on keypress of the SearchBar.

I managed to get the **SearchBar** property change to work but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong in the filtering logic.

Ideally I want to update the list as I type in the search term in the `SearchBar`. I've searched the API on the Telerik site, there wasn't really any examples I could find.

**XML**

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
    <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ isLoading }}" />
    <ActionBar title="People">
    </ActionBar>
    <GridLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search for someone"></SearchBar>
            <ListView items="{{ peopleList }}" itemTap="showDetail">
                <ListView.itemTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label text="{{ fullName }}" horiztonalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
                        <Label text="{{ company }}" class="info"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ListView.itemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

**JS**

```
var frames = require("ui/frame");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var PeopleListViewModel = require("../../shared/people-viewModel");
var activityIndicatorModule = require("ui/activity-indicator");

var page;
var userkey;

var peopleList = new PeopleListViewModel([]);
var pageData = new Observable({ peopleList: peopleList });

exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    userkey = userkey || page.navigationContext.userkey;

    peopleList.load(userkey); // fetch data from the backend

    var searchBar = page.getViewById("searchBar");
    searchBar.on("propertyChange", function (args) {
        var searchText = args.object.text;
        if (searchText === "") {
            // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE.
        } else {
            peopleList.filter(function (element, index, array) {
                // DOESN"T WORK PROPERLY
                console.log("element: ", JSON.stringify(element));
                return element.fullName == searchText;
            });
            console.log("Text types: ", searchText);
        }
    });
};

exports.showDetail = function(args) {
    var person = peopleList.getItem(args.index);
    var navigateEntry = {
        moduleName: "views/people/people-detail",
        context: { person: person },
        animated: false
    };
    frames.topmost().navigate(navigateEntry);
};
```

**PeopleListViewModel.js**

```
var config = require("./config");
var fetchModule = require("fetch");
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

function PeopleListViewModel(people) {
    var viewModel = new ObservableArray(people);

    viewModel.load = function (userKey) {

        return fetchModule.fetch(config.baseUrl + "/api/people/all/" + userKey)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                data.forEach(function (person) {
                    viewModel.push(person);
                });
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("Error: ", error);
            });
    };

    viewModel.empty = function () {
        while (viewModel.length) {
            viewModel.pop();
        }
    };

    return viewModel;
}

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log("Error occurred");
    }
}

module.exports = PeopleListViewModel;
```

**Updated people-list**

```
var frames = require("ui/frame");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var PeopleListViewModel = require("../../shared/people-viewModel");
var activityIndicatorModule = require("ui/activity-indicator");

var page;
var userkey;

var peopleList = new PeopleListViewModel([]);
var pageData = new Observable({ peopleList: peopleList });
var resultList = new ObservableArray([]);

exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    userkey = userkey || page.navigationContext.userkey;

    peopleList.load(userkey);

    var searchBar = page.getViewById("searchBar");
    searchBar.on("propertyChange", function (args) {
        var searchText = args.object.text;

        if (searchText === "") {

        } else {

            while (resultList.length > 0) {
                resultList.pop();
            }   

            peopleList.forEach(function (element) {
                if (element.fullName === searchText) {
                    resultList.push(element);
                }
            });
        }   
    });

};
```

Comment: What is the actual behaviour you're seeing with the filtering? Is it not filtering at all or are you getting blank array or wrong output?

Comment: @AkashAgrawal it doesn't work at all. I basically want the search bar to act as a text filter for the list below, which is just a list of people with their fullName + company displayed.

Comment: Can you show us the PeopleListViewModel. Is `filter` a custom method or just the javascript `filter` method of an array? If the latter, you're not assigning it to anything.

Comment: @EmilOberg I've added the view model file. Sorry I'm still new to NativeScript, a lot of it is still very confusing to me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. If you want to filter your data after every character has changed in search-bar you can try my solution.

**Definitions**
My playerList is your peopleList. This is the data from view-model.
resultList is an array where the data will be pushed.

```
var observableArrayModule = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var playerList = new PlayerListViewModel([]);
var resultList = new observableArrayModule([]);

var pageData = new observableModule.Observable({
  resultList: resultList,
  player: ""
});
```

**Inside expors.loaded()**

```
  page = args.object;
  searchBar = page.getViewById("search-bar");
  page.bindingContext = pageData;
```

**Load Initial Data - inside expors.loaded()**

We are loading initial data when user navigates to the screen for the first time. We are also pushing the same data to resultList since we are using {{resultList}} in xml. You can add loadingIndicator while the list is populated.

```
playerList
.load()
.then(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    playerList.forEach(function (element) {
      pageData.resultList.push(element);
    });
  }, 1000);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  dialogsModule.alert({
    message: "An error occurred while loading players.",
    okButtonText: "OK"
  });
});
```

**Clear autofocus - inside expors.loaded()**

This is to prevent keyboard from opening on initial screen navigation.

```
  if (searchBar.ios) {
    searchBar.ios.endEditing(true);
  } else if (searchBar.android) {
      searchBar.android.clearFocus();
  }
```

**Search data when character has changed - inside expors.loaded()**

I am calling filter functionality. Lodash _.debounce function is used to delay looping through resultList array. Without it, the app would loop every time letter is typed. Now we are waiting for user to stop typing to start looping.

```
searchBar.on('propertyChange', _.debounce(searchList, 500));
```

**searchList Function**

This is the actual loop. You can change element.name for your needs.

```
function searchList(args) {
  var searchText = args.object.text;
  while(resultList.length > 0) {
    resultList.pop();
  }
  playerList.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) >= 0) {
      resultList.push(element);
    }
  });
}
```

**Hide keyboard if search-bar is cleared - inside exports.loaded()**

And finally we want to hide the keyboard if user clears the search-bar.

```
searchBar.on(searchBarModule.SearchBar.clearEvent, function (args) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    searchBar.dismissSoftInput();
  }, 10);
});
```

PS

You probably solved your issue, but this could help someone else in the future.

Comment: Thanks it gave me direction for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so your problem is a Javascript problem than a NativeScript problem. For the sake of this problem, think of observable arrays as just your ordinary arrays.

In your JS you're creating a new `PeopleListViewModel` which you're then attaching to the bindingContext via the `pageData` object. So far so good. Then you're calling the `load` method on the `PeopleListViewModel` (It returns a promise which you're not really doing anything with but for this specific problem it doesn't matter).

However, when text is inputed you're not really doing anything. This is your code:

```
        peopleList.filter(function (element, index, array) {
            // DOESN"T WORK PROPERLY
            console.log("element: ", JSON.stringify(element));
            return element.fullName == searchText;
        });
```

`peopleList` is an instance of `PeopleListViewModel` which returns an `ObservableArray`. The ObservableArray does indeed have a method called `filter` (which works just like filter of a regular array. Check out the [NativeScript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/observable-array/ObservableArray.html) and [Javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of `filter`).

What you need to understand here is that `filter` **returns a new array** with the filtered results. Doing `peopleList.filter()` will send that new array into empty space. You want to `var yourNewFilteredArray = peopleList.filter()`. But you don't really want to *redefine* the array bound to the binding context, you want to modify the content of it.

Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
/*
 * Attach a new obsersable array to the binding context.
 * you can prepopulate it with the data from the 
 * PeopleListViewModel if you want to
 */
var resultList = new ObservableArray([]);
var pageData = new Observable({ resultList: resultList });

/*
 * Then on search/filter you want to modify this new
 * array. Here I first remove every item in it and then
 * push matching items to it.
 */
searchBar.on("propertyChange", function (args) {
    var searchText = args.object.text;
    // ...

    while(resultList.length > 0) {
        resultList.pop();
    }

    peopleList.forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.fullName === searchText) {
            resultList.push(element);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Here's some code from an app which does pretty much what you're trying to do: https://github.com/emiloberg/oppna-program-reklistan-app/blob/master/src/app/views/search.js#L70-L93

Comment: What is ```searchResults``` in your example above. It looks like a new array/collection? Is it the same as resultList in your example above?

Comment: I've updated the question with the updated js file, I'm still not sure what I"m missing, can you please have a look and let me know what I'm still not doing correctly?

Comment: Have you also updated your XML to print the data from the `resultList` rather than the `peopleList`?

Comment: I have tried to change it to result list, but this would mean I have no data bound as the array is empty to start with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106381/discussion-between-thelazychap-and-emil-oberg).